# how to update the records from My DataTable within a BackgroundWorker and show the progress

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I get this error if I click a button that starts the backgroundworker twice.

This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently

How can i make it work when it update the records ?

this is my code

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("****"))
        {
            con.Open();


            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE indebtedness SET collected=@collected,Payment_Date=@Payment_Date,Payment_Date2=@Payment_Date2 WHERE Subscriber_No=@Subscriber_No and company_name=@company_name and indebtedness_name=@indebtedness_name ", con))
            {
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_name", company_name.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@indebtedness_name", indebtedness_name.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment_Date2", DateTime.Today.ToString());
                com.Parameters.Add("@Payment_Date", SqlDbType.Date);
                com.Parameters.Add("@Subscriber_No", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@collected", SqlDbType.Decimal) { Precision = 18, Scale = 3 });

                int countSuccess = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {

                    com.Parameters["@Subscriber_No"].Value = Convert.ToInt64(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                    com.Parameters["@collected"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                    com.Parameters["@Payment_Date"].Value = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value); //hope this is a date, not a string. If it's a string, parse it instead
                    int numUpd = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    countSuccess += numUpd;
                }
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                progressBar1.Show();

                MessageBox.Show($"Successfully UPDATED {countSuccess} of {dataGridView1.Rows.Count} rows");

            }
        }

 private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label6.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
        if(label6.Text=="100%")
        {
            label7.Text = "Record UPdated Successfully .. ";
        }
    }
```

i try to update the records and show the result is the bar when it working

Comment: Ok, so you really want to ask how to update the database from the records of your DataTable within a BackgroundWorker and show the progress? If so, then please update the question (including the title)

Comment: Yes, move the update process inside the DoWork of the BackgroundWorker. But be careful: You cannot access the gridview from a background thread, so you have to copy the data from the grid. Then pass this data to the background worker and use that to update the database

Comment: @SirRufo can you explain it into the answer plz

Comment: The ProgressChanged event has a state property where you can pass data from backgroundworker to main thread.  So you can pass the data to the ProgressChanged Event and write to the table in the event.

Comment: @jdweng can you explain it to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code would look like this :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class State
    {
        public List<string> data { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyBackgroundWorker
    {
        public static BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

        public void Test()
        {
            State state = new State();
            state.data = new List<string> { "Some Data" };
            int progress = 50;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress, state);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        private void BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            State state = e.UserState as State;
            //add code to write to datatable here
        }
    }
}
```